# Convert a row into a combine, c() as a vector in r and then use vectors to calculate the cosine similarity

Tags: r, dataframe, cosine-similarity

Hello I have a very large data frame and it is a partial part:

[image]

```
v1 <- c('i1', 'i10', 'i11')
v2 <- c(0.11, 0.07, 0.114)
v3 <- c(0.07, 0.08, 0.03)
df <- data.frame(cbind(v1, v2, v3))
```

How can I write some codes to convert each row into a combined vector, `x <- c()`?

that is, my expected output should be and the variable names need to be from column `V1`  :

```
i1 <- c(0.11014318, 0.07302843, 0.01360761, 0.10619829, 0.14513045)
i10 <- c(0.07360007, 0.08013833, 0.13104657, 0.13174247, 0.14256615)
i11 <- c(0.11418245, 0.03300573, 0.11425297, 0.13686428, 0.03367279)
```

After converting each row into a vector, I need to compute the cosine similarity among these vectors so that's why I need to split each row and save them as vectors with names from the first column `V1`.

```
library(lsa)
cosine(i1, i10)
cosine(i1, i11)
cosine(i10, i11)
```

**The following question**

Hello SamR. Thanks for your kind help but I do not know why it does not work when adding more columns `V4` and `V5` and one more row with the ID `i12`? Thanks so much for your patience and help.

```
data_matrix <- function(df){
  data_matrix  <- tail(t(df), -1) |>
    sapply(as.numeric) |>
    matrix(
        nrow = ncol(df)-1, 
        ncol = nrow(df), 
        dimnames = list(
            seq_len(nrow(df)-1), # rows
            df[,1] # columns
        )
    ) 
}

v1 <- c('i1', 'i10', 'i11', 'i12')
v2 <- c(0.11, 0.07, 0.114, 0.67)
v3 <- c(0.07, 0.08, 0.03, 087)
v4 <- c(0.12, 0.13, 0.14, 0.18)
v5 <- c(0.19, 0.21, 0.22, 0.22)
df <- data.frame(cbind(v1, v2, v3, v4, v5))
df

data_matrix(df)
```

It just returns the error:

```
Error in matrix(sapply(tail(t(df), -1), as.numeric), nrow = ncol(df) -  : 
  length of 'dimnames' [1] not equal to array extent
```

Comment: the idea behind a data frame is to organize similar items with same properties. The bigger your data the more you profit from not splitting rows apart.

Comment: Thanks for your comment but I need to calculate the cosine similarities for every vector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another approach would be to use `apply` over each row, which allows you to set the environment directly:

```r
apply(df, 1, function(x) assign(x[1], tail(x, -1), envir = globalenv()))
```

However I agree with @danlooo's comment: I can't think of any reason that you would want to do this.

### Edit: how to calculate cosine similarity matrix (following comment)

If you want to calculate a cosine similarity matrix it's better to start off with a matrix than to clutter up your global environment, and then have to do a potentially large combination of pairwise calculations.

First get the data into the right format, a numeric matrix with column names which are the first column of your data frame:

```r
data_matrix  <- tail(t(df), -1) |>
    sapply(as.numeric) |>
    matrix(
        nrow = ncol(df) - 1, 
        ncol = nrow(df), 
        dimnames = list(
            seq_len(ncol(df)-1), # rows
            df[,1] # columns
        )
    ) 

data_matrix
#     i1  i10   i11
# 1 0.11 0.07 0.114
# 2 0.07 0.08 0.030
```

Then it is straightforward to calculate the cosine similarity:

```r
library(lsa)
cosine(data_matrix)

#            i1       i10       i11
# i1  1.0000000 0.9595950 0.9525148
# i10 0.9595950 1.0000000 0.8283488
# i11 0.9525148 0.8283488 1.0000000
```

Comment: Thanks! The reason why I want to do it is that I need to calculate the cosine similarity among them.

Comment: @Fox_Summer Now that I know what you are trying to do, I have updated my response with a better way to do it!

Comment: Hello SamR, I have another question and please see my update above. Why does data_matrix not work when I add two more columns and one row? Thanks so much for your help and patience.

Comment: I made a mistake in the `dimnames` argument. It should be `ncol(df)-1` not `nrow(df)-1`. I have updated the answer. I didn't notice because it had the same number of rows as columns. Also - I am assuming you are going to do something else in the function, or return `data_matrix`? Otherwise the variable disappears when the function ends.

Comment: Yes and I am going to return ```data_matrix``` since I have different two datasets. I just do not want to repeat the chunk of code. :) Again, thanks so much.

Answer (score 2):

You can use and `split` or `asplit` to split the rows, with `setNames` to set names of the list elements with your first column, and then use `list2env` to add elements of the list to the global environment:

```r
l <- setNames(split(df[-1], seq(nrow(df))), df[,1])

# $i1
#     v2   v3
# 1 0.11 0.07
# 
# $i10
#     v2   v3
# 2 0.07 0.08
# 
# $i11
#      v2   v3
# 3 0.114 0.03

list2env(l, .GlobalEnv)
```

other splitting options include `asplit` and `row`:

```r
asplit(df[-1], 1)
split(df[-1], row(df[-1])[, 1])
as.list(as.data.frame(t(df[, -1])))
```

Comment: `list2env(l, .GlobalEnv)` to build objects to the global environment.

Comment: When I use this function, it by default builds it to the global env, but better be specific. Good input

Comment: Good point! `list2env` of my R version(4.1.2) defaults to build objects to a new environment, not global.

Comment: Nice answer, +1! We can also use `list2env(by(df, v1, `[`, -1), .GlobalEnv)` if we prefer code-golfing.

Answer (score 0):

Another variation of previous answers:

```r
lapply(seq_len(nrow(df)), \(.) assign(df$v1[.], unlist(df[.,-1]), envir = .GlobalEnv))
```

That is, for each (`lapply`) row (`seq_len(nrow(df))`, `\(.)`), transform all the columns up to the first into vectors (`unlist(df[.,-1])`), and then `assign` those vectors to the first column strings (`unlist(df[.,-1])`) in the global environment (`envir = .GlobalEnv`).

And faster, improving also @SamR solution (in which transforming the `df` to an array, all numeric data become character):

```r
list2env(setNames(apply(df[-1], 1, identity, simplify = FALSE), nm = df$v1), .GlobalEnv)
```

But not faster than @Maël solutions

```r
v1 <- paste0("i", 1:1e+3)
lapply(2:200, \(.) assign(paste0("v", .), rnorm(1e+3), envir = .GlobalEnv))
df <- do.call("data.frame", args = sapply(ls(pattern = "^v\\d+$"), get, envir = .GlobalEnv, simplify = FALSE))
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
    list2env(setNames(as.list(as.data.frame(t(df[, -1]))), df[, 1]), .GlobalEnv), 
    list2env(setNames(asplit(df[-1], 1), df[, 1]), .GlobalEnv), 
    list2env(setNames(apply(df[-1], 1, identity, simplify = FALSE), nm = df$v1), .GlobalEnv), 
    check = "equal")
Unit: milliseconds
                                                                                          expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval
             list2env(setNames(as.list(as.data.frame(t(df[, -1]))), df[, 1]), .GlobalEnv) 5.548269 5.731607 9.444446 5.864418 6.114002 37.83762   100
                               list2env(setNames(asplit(df[-1], 1), df[, 1]), .GlobalEnv) 7.421431 7.568999 9.336666 7.639897 7.800458 31.90791   100
 list2env(setNames(apply(df[-1], 1, identity, simplify = FALSE), nm = df$v1), .GlobalEnv) 8.031275 8.201781 9.796997 8.332828 8.512478 34.35403   100
```

The other solutions by @Maël (using `split(df[-1], seq(nrow(df)))` and `split(df[-1], row(df[-1])[, 1])`) and the solution by @benson23 `setNames(lapply(1:nrow(df), function(x) df[x, -1]), df[, 1])` produce `data.frame` outputs instead of vectors.